# Teamcity - FTP upload failed with error "425 Cannot open data connection"

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, ftp, teamcity

I am using Teamcity to deploy my Web App in FTP. The deployment worked very well until Monday. Now it doesn't work anymore. I didn't make any changes on Teamcity. The problem: FTP transfer starts normally. Some files are transferred. Then it interrupts with an FTP error:' 425 Cannot open data connection'.
The FTP deployment works fine on all my other Web Apps. Can you give me a hint about this problem?[teamcity step configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqYVd.png)

Logs :

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 257 "/" is current directory.

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] > PASV

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 227 Entering Passive Mode (104,40,210,230,39,137).

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] > NLST

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 226 Transfer complete.

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] > CWD site

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 250 CWD command successful.

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] > PASV

[13:57:10]i:     [Step 1/1] < 425 Cannot open data connection.

[13:57:10]E:     [Step 1/1] Failed to upload artifacts via FTP. Reply was: 425 Cannot open data connection.

[13:57:10]E:     [Step 1/1] Step Deploy (FTP Upload) failed
[13:57:10] : Publishing internal artifacts
[13:57:10] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: 
[13:57:10] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: 
[13:57:10]E: Unknown build problem reported on agent
[13:57:10] : Build finished

Comment: if nothing has changed in TeamCity, then something changed on th other side (azure).  Please, consult the Azure's FTP server logs for more details on why it replies with 425

Answer (score 0):

Firewall issue me think.

FTP actually transfers using a random port, you can however tell it to use a random port from a range e.g 9100-9200.

It only uses port 21 for listing.